# In list1 set member from list2

Tags: c#, linq

I have this setup:

```
class Person
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

static void Main()
{
    int[] nums = { 1, 2, 3 };
    Person[] persons = { new Person(), new Person(), new Person() }

    for (int i = 0; i < persons.Length; i++)
    {
        persons[i].Age = nums[i];
    }

    persons.ToList().ForEach(p => Console.WriteLine(p.Age));
}
```

So each Persons' age gets set.

Is it possible to replace the for loop with something in LINQ?
I have tried this:

```
persons.Zip(nums, (person, num) => person.Age = num);
```

It compiled and ran, but the result is not correct...

**UPDATE**
The answers and comments are great and very useful feedback.
I will use a *foreach loop* instead as recommended.

```
foreach (var item in person.Zip(nums, Tuple.Create))
{
    item.Item1.Age = item.Item2;
}
```

Comment: Linq is designed for querying, not for changing source data. Your loop is very simple, why are you so concerned?

Comment: What musefan said. Just use a for loop, it'll be easier to read.

Comment: I agree. I should use a loop.

Comment: @Mc_Topaz Do you numbers always have to be `1`, `2`, `3`? Why `Zip` method isn't working here? It should do what you want.

Comment: At this point, I would suggest the `Console.WriteLine` should be in the same loop - I don't think you should convert an `IEnumerable` to a `List` just to use the `ForEach` extension method. If you want that, write a `ForEach` extension for `IEnumerable`. Also, I think the `for` was better than the `foreach` that creates a tuple every iteration.

Comment: mark a comment as proper answer, someone is downvoting them even if they are correct

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question would be in this particular case to NOT use LINQ. My advice is to avoid abusing LINQ methods like `.ToList(), .ToArray()` etc, since it has a huge impact on performance. You iterate through the collection and creating a new collection. Very often simple `foreach` much more readable and understandable than a train of LINQ methods.

Answer (score -1):

Linq does not modify collections
Only one way to proceed

```
 void Main()
{
    int[] nums = { 1, 2, 3 };
    var persons = nums.Select(n=>new Person{Age=n});

}
```

After that every person in persons will have provided Age.

Comment: this was my answer and it got -4

Answer (score -4):

Linq is usually used to query and transform some data.

In case you can change how `persons` are created, this will be the best approach:

```
Person[] persons = nums.Select(n => new Person { Age = n }).ToArray();
```

If you already have the list of persons, go with the `foreach` loop. LinQ should be only used for querying, not modifying

Comment: Foreach does not have an overload with an index.

Comment: Not only the overhead of creating new objects but also the overhead that you have to create a deep copy of the old object. Consider that `Person` could have 100 more properties. Creating new object instances could also have an undesired side-effect if the old instances were still referenced somewhere else.

Comment: Do you guys read? "In case you can change how persons are created, this will be the best approach" this introduces zero overhead @TimSchmelter

Answer (score -4):

You could do it with linq but you're better of using a simple for loop.

Here's one (convoluted) way to do it:

```
persons
    .Select((x, i) => new {Person = x, Id =i})
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(x=> x.Person.Age = nums[x.Id]);
```

Comment: When i see `ToList` + `ForEach` i could cry. Why creating a completely new list with all the items in the old(could be millions) just to be able to use `List.ForEach`. Use `foreach` instead.

Comment: Yes, you're better of using a foreach loop. Still, this works and uses linq like the poster requested... It's funny how when people learn somehing like Linq suddenly all problems must be solved using it.